# Как получить уровень вложенности для каждого элемента многомерного массива?

Tags: php, select2

Массив имеет вид:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Гардероб
            [parent_id] => 0
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [title] => Мужской
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [title] => Одежда
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                            [childs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [11] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 11
                                                            [title] => Куртки
                                                            [parent_id] => 5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [title] => Обувь
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                        )

                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [title] => Аксессуары
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [title] => Женский
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [8] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                            [title] => Одежда
                                            [parent_id] => 4
                                            [childs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [12] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 12
                                                            [title] => Куртки
                                                            [parent_id] => 8
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [9] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [title] => Обувь
                                            [parent_id] => 4
                                        )

                                    [10] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 10
                                            [title] => Аксессуары
                                            [parent_id] => 4
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Электроника
            [parent_id] => 0
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 13
                            [title] => Ноутбуки
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [title] => Смартфоны
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [title] => Планшеты
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [title] => Беспроводные АС
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [title] => Умные часы и браслеты
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [title] => Книги
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

)
```

Нужно получить уровень вложенности каждого элемента массива. Необходимо для построения "лесенки" - задавать отступ для каждого пункта меню, в зависимости от уровня вложенности. Массив выводится в `<select>` так что одним `css` тут не отделаться.

Comment: Вы сейчас как-то выводите этот массив? Рекурсивно?

Comment: @cheops да, вывожу. Но он выводится обычным списком без отступов. нужно получать при выводе уровень вложенности конкретного пункта и добавлять ему соответствующий padding или количество пробелов ;nbsp;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно в рекурсивную функцию добавить дополнительный параметр $offset, который будет задавать отступ и увеличиваться при каждом рекурсивном вызове функции

```
<?php
$arr = Array(
  Array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Гардероб',
    'parent_id' => '0',
    'childs' => Array(
      Array(
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'Мужской',
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'childs' => Array(
          Array(
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => 'Одежда',
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'childs' => Array(
              Array(
                'id' => 11,
                'title' => 'Куртки',
                'parent_id' => 5
              )
            )
          ),
          Array(
            'id' => 6,
            'title' => 'Обувь',
            'parent_id' => 3
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
function select($arr, $offset = '')
{
  foreach($arr as $val) {
    echo "<option name='{$val['id']}'>{$offset}".
       htmlspecialchars($val['title'])."</option>";
    if(!empty($val['childs']))
       select($val['childs'], $offset . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  }
}
echo "<select name='hierarchy'>";
echo select($arr);
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: ваш вариант работает именно так, как нужно. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, только рекурсией.

Как-то так:

```
function buildResult($level, $myarray_arr) {
if (empty($myarray)) return false;
foreach($myarray_arr as $myarray) {
$result[] = array('id'=>$myarray['id'], 'title'=>$myarray['title'], 'parent_id'=>$myarray['parent_id'], 'level'=>$level, 'childs'=>buildResult($level+1, $myarray['childs']));
}
return $result;
}

$show_arr = buildResult(0, $myarray_arr);
```

Теперь у вас будет $level, который вы можете учитывать при выводе.

Comment: то есть ваша функция создаёт ещё один элемент со значением уровня? `return` не нужен или вы просто забыли указать?

Comment: Вы правы, должен быть и ретурн, и нашел еще 2 опечатки своих: в ресульте должен добавлять элемент, а не просто присваиваться; нужен элемент, в который изначально соберется весь наш рекурсивный buildResult()... Прошу прощения, поправил. По сути, да, просто добавлен еще один элемент со значением уровня.

Comment: не работает, функция не возвращает ничего. Даже пустого массива не выдаёт(

Comment: я бессилен перед вами... вы даже не думали о том, как работает функция, что в нее нужно минимально ваш массив передать ... это треш (((